# node.js api with array's

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongoose

I'm pretty new to node.js and javascript. I'm builded and api and out of the sudden the data model changed and now i'm kinda lost.

This is my code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


//create schema
var MedicSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  nombre:{
      type: String,
      required: true
  },
  especialidad:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  ranking:{
    type: Number,
  },

  direccion: [{
        direccion: {type: String, required: true},
        telefono: {type: String},
        horario:{type: String}
        }],

    foto:{
    type: String,
}
});

MedicSchema.find({})
.populate('direccion')
.exec(function (err, medic) {
    console.log(medic.direccion); // This should have your information now
});

//export model
module.exports = MedicSchema;
```

I'm able to send data to the direccion array... but when i call the api; i get this:

```
{
    "_id": "557839b36bcdd00e09173e36",
    "nombre": "Sra. Hong",
    "especialidad": "general",
    "__v": 0,
    "direccion": [
        {
            "_id": "55a44392b2e774572b957a8e"
        },
        {
            "_id": "55a44392b2e774572b957a8d"
        }
    ]
}
```

i can't find a way to call the details of the array.

**edit:**  i posted it on bitbucket  https://bitbucket.org/weput/api-server

Comment: how are you calling the api? can you post the call?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'call the details'? Maybe show us an example?

Comment: i call the api on the web browser

Comment: the "direccion" array have 3 set of properties. In the example posted i show 2 set of data on the aray... unfortunatelly it shows only the id.

Answer (score 0):

You need to .populate your "direccion" array.  For example:

```
MedicSchema.find({})
.populate('direccion')
.exec(function (err, medic) {
    console.log(medic.direccion); // This should have your information now
});
```

Comment: I dunno why; but this piece of code breaks my node.js :(

Comment: Can you post your existing code you were using that produced the result in your question with the missing array data?  I can simply modify that for you.

Comment: I think there was a little misunderstanding.  You can't put the code I gave you in your model/schema js.  You use that to retrieve the model in your controller.  When you say you're "calling your API" what controller are you calling?  Or are you using some framework that uses blueprints or something automatic so you don't have a controller?  If so, that's your issue, as the automatic routes will not do complex things like .populate(). So you'd need to make your own controller and use the code I gave you.

Comment: there was a misunderstanding.

Comment: This is my controller:

`var restful = require ('node-restful');

module.exports = function(app, route){

//set controller for REST
var rest = restful.model(
'medic',
 app.models.medic    
).methods(['get', 'put', 'post', 'delete']);
    
//registrer endpoint with the app
    rest.register(app, route);
    
    return function(req, res, next){
    next();
    };
};`

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry but the answer to this is way beyond the scope of your question.  You'll need to read up on how to generate your own endpoint with custom logic (like what I wrote for you above).

Comment: well
im already writting the whole thing again using this tutorial

https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4

I'll let you know how goes

Comment: A friend of mine point me to sailsjs too...
that project has very good documentation... however, the blueprint features lures me :D

Comment: Blueprints are awesome for quick development for a prototype.  And then if/when you're ready to make a production level app, you simply turn them off and make your own endpoints.  It's awesome for building as you go :).